# Как записать данные в файл из консоли после команды?

Tags: java, filestream

Как сделать так, чтобы данные вводимые в консоль, записывались в файл после ввода определённой команды ? В моём случае набираем какие-то данные в консоль и после ввода "end", всё что набиралось ранее, должно записаться в файл. У меня же записывается только сама команда, а всё что набираю в консоли до неё, не записывается. Вот мой код:

```
public static void writeToFileFromConsole(String path){

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        FileWriter writer = null;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;

        System.out.println("Enter file content to write in the file:");

        try {
            String line;
            do {
                line = br.readLine();
                writer = new FileWriter(path, true);
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

                bufferedWriter.append("\n");
                bufferedWriter.append(line);
            }
            while (!line.equals("wr"));
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Can't write to file with path " + path);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                br.close();
                reader.close();
                if (bufferedWriter != null){
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                }
                if (writer != null){
                    writer.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.err.println("File with path " + path + " not found" );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит создавать `FileWriter` перед началом выполнения цикла. Тогда данные не будут теряться, иначе же, у вас на каждой итерации создается новый объект. Например так:

```
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true));

 String line;
 do {
     line = br.readLine();
     writer.append("\n");
     writer.append(line);
 } while (!"wr".equals(line));
```

Comment: и оборачивать его в отдельный try - cath ?

Comment: вообще хороший  тон оборачивать все это в try catch finally, но если вы пишите под версию java где этого нет, то да, оборачиваете в try catch или прокидывайте исключение из метода. зависит от логики которую вы реализовываете

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.